# why do i get wrong values from a string when converted to int

Tags: c#, .net, modbus

I am trying to send by [ModBus](https://www.modbus.org/) Protocol the date and time from my system.
The problem is when I convert it to int, the value changes to strange numbers. Can you please tell me why?

Here is my code:

```
var time = DateTime.Now;
string formattedTime = time.ToString("ss, mm, HH, dd, MM, yy");
int ss = formattedTime[0];
int mm = formattedTime[1];
int hh = formattedTime[2];
int dd = formattedTime[3];
int MM = formattedTime[4];
int yy = formattedTime[5];
```

Comment: because it returns only the char in byte.

Comment: Add your time directly to your variables in required format "var ss = int.Parse(time.ToString("ss"));"

Comment: `formattedTime[0]` is the first `char` in the string. `char` is implicitly converted to `int`, but it returns the ASCII value of the character which is not what you're expecting.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're converting individual chars to int. The conversion works, as expected returning the value of the character.

As an added remark, `formattedTime[2]` corresponds to a comma, not the hours component.

Your DateTime object already have all those informations directly accessible without having to format it into a string and trying to get the information back.

So, if you just need to access the values, try :
`time.Seconds`

If that's fine for you, there are similar properties for all of the date components.

Answer (score 1):

I get the impression that your intention with this line

```
string formattedTime = time.ToString("ss, mm, HH, dd, MM, yy");
```

is to cast the individual values `.ToArray()`?
That is not how you would do that. The `.ToString()` method returns a string, not an array. Therefore you can't access `formattedTime` by index, like an array as it is not an array.
So what you are doing is indeed, as others have pointed out, return the byte value of the character at the `[i]` position of the `formattedTime` string.

If you quickly want to achieve to separate the values as per what seems to be your intention, then easiest to use the appropriate properties of the `DateTime` class object as per below;

```
var time = DateTime.Now;
        
int ss = time.Second;
int mm = time.Minute;
int hh = time.Hour;
int dd = time.Day;
int MM = time.Month;
int yy = time.Year;
```

If you insist on getting those values into an Array, follow the below;

```
int[] formattedTime = new int[6];

formattedTime[0] = time.Second;
formattedTime[1] = time.Minute;
formattedTime[2] = time.Hour;
formattedTime[3] = time.Day;
formattedTime[4] = time.Month;
formattedTime[5] = time.Year;
```

If you wish to have that in your originally intended string, try;

```
string strFormattedTime = string.Join(", ", formattedTime);
```

Alternatively and following closer to your original intention though not as concise as the above solution;

```
var time = DateTime.Now;

string formattedTime = time.ToString("ss, mm, HH, dd, MM, yy");

var formattedArray = formattedTime.Split(",");                   // split on the ','
formattedArray = formattedArray.Select(c => c.Trim()).ToArray(); // trim leading spaces
var intFormattedArray = formattedArray.Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c)).ToArray();  // convert to int array
```

You can then access the int as per your original intention;

```
int ss = intFormattedTime[0];
```

Comment: Thank you all vety much, it was very helpfull.

Comment: @ShayAvitapl if any of the answers has answered your question then select it as the answer to your question, that will help the process flow of SO?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the days, seconds , etc, directly from datetime. In case you can use it, you'll avoid to handle diferent string representations of datetime.

```
  var time = DateTime.Now;
  int ss = time.Second;
  int mm = time.Minute;
  int hh = time.Hour;
  int dd = time.Day;
  int MM = time.Month;
  int yy = time.Year;
```